# fpdf- Page break not working

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have created pdf page using the following lines of code :

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);               
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
```

But when the contents of the page overflows it doesn't get displayed to the next page. Instead there is always a single page. How can I solve this?